# How to add white space at the bottom of a pdf page using PDFsharp

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdfsharp

I am trying to stamp the bottom of each PDF page with text. The issue is, I don't want the new text to cover the existing contents of the PDF page. I tried to increase the size of the page, this results into resizing all the contents which lead to the same issue. Here is my code sample:

```
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            PdfSharp.Pdf.PdfDocument PDFDoc = PdfSharp.Pdf.IO.PdfReader.Open(@"C:\Users\Desktop\name.pdf", PdfDocumentOpenMode.Import);

            PdfSharp.Pdf.PdfDocument PDFNewDoc = new PdfSharp.Pdf.PdfDocument();

            for (int Pg = 0; Pg < PDFDoc.Pages.Count; Pg++)
            {
                PdfSharp.Pdf.PdfPage pdfPage = PDFNewDoc.AddPage(PDFDoc.Pages[Pg]);
                pdfPage.Height += 100;
                // Add height at bottom of the page
                XRect rect = new XRect(0, 0, pdfPage.Width, pdfPage.Height + 100);
                pdfPage.MediaBox = new PdfSharp.Pdf.PdfRectangle(rect);
                //   pdfPage.Width = XUnit.FromInch(7.50);
                //pdfPage.Height = XUnit.FromInch(12);


                XGraphics gfx = XGraphics.FromPdfPage(PDFNewDoc.Pages[Pg]);
                XFont font = new XFont("Arial", 10, XFontStyle.Regular);
                //rect calls new size
                gfx.DrawString("something", font, XBrushes.Black, rect, XStringFormats.BottomCenter);
            

            }
             PDFNewDoc.Save(@"C:\Users\Desktop\EditedPdf.pdf");


        }

    }
```

I did research on this topic but I couldn't find helpful solutions. Thank you
Also, a suggestion was to shrink the content of the PDF page this will provide white space at all the sides of the page. Then I can add my text at the bottom. It is not an optimal solution, but better than no solution. Unfortunately, I don't know how to achieve that as well; any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a new document and add a page to it with the size of your original document plus the additional space you need. Then copy the content of your original document into the new document with `DrawImage` but pay attention that you don't draw over the extra space you created.

In this example I added 40pts, which are about 14,1 mm.

```
PdfDocument outputDocument = new PdfDocument();
PdfPage outputPage = outputDocument.AddPage();
XPdfForm inputForm = XPdfForm.FromFile(inputFilePath);

outputPage.Width = inputForm.Page.Width;
outputPage.Height = inputForm.Page.Height + 40;

XGraphics gfx = XGraphics.FromPdfPage(outputPage);
XRect box = new XRect(0, 0, outputPage.Width, outputPage.Height - 40);
gfx.DrawImage(inputForm, box);

outputDocument.Save(outputFilePath);
```